# Pick a photo by using iPad camera and get the file name

Tags: ios, ipad

I've to develop an iPad app in which I have to create a form and to capture a pic by using the iPad camera.
The output of this app should be a csv file in which there are a correspondence between photo and data. I guessed that I've to use the filename of the pics.
My solution is to create a csv with following field:

```
Name,Surname,Sex,City,Mail,Nation,IMAGE FILE NAME
```

The question is: it's possible to get the IMAGE FILE NAME after I took it with the iPad camera?

Comment: Where is the image saved to?

Comment: I will save it in the camera roll

Comment: first learn how to take image via your app, then you find the image name (it's the name of the LibraryAsset actually). you'll be able to save it wherever you want latter and give it a name you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that the file name actually means much to you if the image is taken and saved into the photo library, but, if you use `ALAssetsLibrary` and save the image with `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:` then in the completion block you get the destination `NSURL *assetURL`, which you can split to get a file name.